# IBM DB2 using nodejs is throwing connection error as "SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred. SQLSTATE=58004"

Tags: node.js, ibm-db2

I am using ibm_db module to connect to IBM Database using nodejs. I was referring [DB2NodeJs](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/pd/entry/using_ibm_db2_from_node_js4?lang=en). I simply followed this post and used the sample code given in this post. Following were my steps.

```
1. Installed nodejs
2. Installed ibm_db
3. Downloaded the nodedb2test.js file
4. Changed the database details as per my DB2 database
5. Ran this file.
```

I am getting following error

```
error:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004
```

I am new to DB2 using Nodejs. Also I think i provided all details correctly except the db2 driver value DRIVER={DB2}. What should be the value for driver? I never installed any database related driver before. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding `AUTHENTICATION=SERVER` to the connection string.

For example:

`DATABASE=XXXX;HOSTNAME=XXXX;PORT=XXXX;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;AUTHENTICATION=SERVER...`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OSX ? there's an overall problem with db2 when installing the latest 10.10.3 . see here [OS X 10.10.3 - SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b78fe48e-b92c-448f-9154-c5ff4728f77a)

Comment: I am not trying to install db2. I am using nodejs to connect to my existing database.

Comment: I think my main problem is what to set for DRIVER={DB2}? I don't know how to install Driver for DB2 and never installed any database related driver before. Please help.

Comment: Anyone has idea on how to install DB2 driver on Mac and use it using ibm_db nodejs module?